# On div focus, change the sibling css properties without jquery/javascript

Tags: html, css

Fiddle:     http://jsfiddle.net/xLc43uyu/1/

What i want to achieve is, when `.german` div made to focus, background-color of div with class `.germanContent` should change as per the css rule defined. But somehow, it is not happening.

HTML:

```css
#german:focus + .germanContent{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='german'>See in German</div>
<div class='germanContent'>
      Blah blah blah in german
</div>
```

Any lead is appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for `:hover` instead of `:focus` ?

Comment: I wanted to simulate behavior similar to click on div, thus `:focus`. Definitely not `:hover`

Comment: Your previous element is not an input element.

Comment: Can't focus happen on `div` element. Focus can only happen on `input`?

Comment: @RAKESHKUMAR Check my answer and let me know if that's what you need?

Comment: @RAKESHKUMAR I have also updated my answer now... Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` are not focusable, unless you provide them explicitly with a `tabindex`. So, a `tabindex` of `-1` should do the trick. (*-1 will not break your existing tab flow*)

***Snippet***:

```css
#german:focus + .germanContent{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='german' tabindex="-1">See in German</div>
<div class='germanContent'>
    Blah blah blah in german
</div>
```

Per the HTML5 Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute

> The tabindex content attribute allows authors to control whether an
>   element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be
>   reachable using sequential focus navigation, and what is to be the
>   relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus
>   navigation. The name "tab index" comes from the common use of the
>   "tab" key to navigate through the focusable elements.

And for negative tabindex:

> If the value is a negative integer The user agent must set the
>   element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be
>   reached using sequential focus navigation.

And the MDN Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Great!. Can you explain significance of `tabindex`?

Comment: `tabindex` *The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element can take input focus (is focusable)* [MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: @RAKESHKUMAR: tabindex defines the order of focus (especially on form inputs) when you press tab.

Comment: @RAKESHKUMAR: There, added the official reference in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want the blue background when clicking and holding the `<div>`. May be this would help? Try using `:active` instead:

```css
#german:active + .germanContent{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='german'>See in German</div>
<div class='germanContent'>
  Blah blah blah in german
</div>
```

Or if you really need `focus`sing on the non-focussable `<div>` than clicking or something, then you need to add the `tabindex` property to that:

```css
#german:focus + .germanContent{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='german' tabindex="-1">See in German</div>
<div class='germanContent'>
  Blah blah blah in german
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLc43uyu/1/)

```
<div id='german' tabindex="0">See in German</div>
```

add tabindex attribute to german div